# File format is not valid Richtextbox c#

Tags: c#

> Error: File format is not valid in Richtextbox.

My code here:

```
var webClient = new WebClient(); //Make sure to reference System.Net
richTextBox1.Rtf = webClient.DownloadString("http://koolkool.freevnn.com/tool/Documents/invitePK.rtf")
```

Please help me. Image error here: [image]

Answer (score 5):

Well, let's use PowerShell and take a look at what you're actually downloading:

```
PS > $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
PS > $wc.DownloadString("http://koolkool.freevnn.com/tool/Documents/invitePK.rtf")
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(.
.)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].co
nstructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerC
ase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("
e1b925425726f4245ffe50e9fafc1f50");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37
23:55:55 GMT; path=/";location.href="http://koolkool.freevnn.com/tool/Documents/invitePK.rtf?ckattempt=1";</script><nos
cript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript
support</noscript></body></html>
PS >
```

Whoops. It looks like `RichTextBox` doesn't know what to do with that HTML string. *Bad server. I ask for an `.rtf` resource, and you give me some JavaScript junk?*

Comment: You probably should parse that HTML with regex.

Comment: @Ic. Is this server issue? it is sending bad data. But if I download the file using browser then it sent right expected file. So is it not issue with downloading the file in proper way by adding headers with content type etc?

Comment: The server is trying to do something sneaky with JavaScript. That's all I know.

Answer (score 4):

Below lines are from MSDN reference source.

```
string str = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
if (!SZ_RTF_TAG.Equals(str)) // SZ_RTF_TAG ="{\\rtf";
    throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString(SR.InvalidFileFormat));
```

if the value you are assigning is not starting with "{\rtf" microsoft will throw the exception.

If you are assigning the value which starts with "{\rtf" and still facing the issue then issue could be with your OS. Similar issues were started occurring with windows version 1803.

If you have windows version 1803 then disabling the beta feature will solve the issue.

To Disable **Beta: unicode UTF-8 for world wide language support**  **Start**=> **Region & Language settings** => **Related settings** -> **Additional date, time & regional settings** => **Region** -> **Change date, time or number formats** => select **Administrative** tab => **Click on Change System Locale**.. => UnCheck **Beta: unicode UTF-8 for world wide language support** => restart your system.

Comment: Awesome answer. Amazing. Thank So Much. your answer works for me.  Thanks Millions.